# enable IE maximum button when using JavaScript window.open()

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cross-browser

When I using JavaScript `window.open()` in IE, the maximum button is always disabled.

How can I enable the button? I have no problem using Chrome & Firefox.

[image]

Comment: Try passing parameter `resizable=1` with `window.open()` `window.open ("http://www.google.com","mywindow","menubar=1,resizable=1,width=350,height=250");`

Comment: @DON How about answer this question with explaining the details of window.open method.

Comment: AKZap added answer, check with that...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set the parameter value [`resizable=yes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.open#Window_functionality_features)

Try this code:

```
 var url = "www.google.com" // set your url.
 window.open(url, "popUp", "resizable=yes");
```

Comment: I did it but it did not work: window.open('mydoc.aspx?DocID={0}', 'docwindow','resizable:yes;help:off;status:no; dialogheight:600px');

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine in iE when `resizable=yes` is added to the `window.open` function.

My Code :

```
kana = window.open('','kana','menubar=0,location=0,resizable=yes,status=1,width=1,height=1,visible=false,alwaysLowered=yes');
```

Comment: When adding code, you should format it using the Code formatter, shows as double braces ({ }) in edit box